# Function return value defined as a constant

Tags: c, function, constants

I've seen in several occasions functions to be defined with the `const` type qualifier just like that:

```
const int foo (int arg)
```

What is the point in this? Function's return value cannot be changed anyway..

Comment: C/C++ Compilers might behave differently on that.

Comment: You are not confusing this with `const int * foo(int arg)`, are you? Because in that case the `const` will make sense.

Comment: That would truly make sense. But no, I am not confusing it with this.

Comment: What is the purpose of marking it as duplicate, to reference the whole audience to the worse-given question? Question.. that I couldn't even understand as well as notice it mentions C++11, which is something completely different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the C spec (C99, section 6.7.3):

> The properties associated with qualified types are meaningful only for expressions that are lvalues.

Functions are not lvalues, so `const` keyword for them has no meaning. Compiler will ignore them during compilation.

Reference: [Online C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: Looks like this is also true in C11 according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/const and the working standard ISO/IEC 9899:201x at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf in section 6.7.3 on page 120 has the same language.

Answer (score 13):

In C, it is indeed useless, and compilers may emit corresponding warnings:

```
$ echo 'const int foo (int arg);' | clang -Weverything -fsyntax-only -xc -
<stdin>:1:1: warning: 'const' type qualifier on return type has no effect
      [-Wignored-qualifiers]
const int foo (int arg);
^~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: EiC and gcc under windows detect no warning/error messages though.

Comment: @Malina: gcc (using 4.9.2 over here) does if you add `-Wextra`